# How do I use dayjs in Vite for Vue or React?

Tags: vite, dayjs

If you attempt to import dayjs into a Vue/React app using Vite you will find it fails. Vite only works with ESM modules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found you need to import the esm module directly and then it will work correctly with Vite run/build.

```
import dayjs from 'dayjs/esm/index.js'
```

Comment: Very strange. How come such a modern library has an issue like that?

Answer (score 0):

DayJS Docs are confusing. Vite dev working OK, BUT facing errors on vite build/preview. Problem was in my code:

**WRONG**:

```js
import dayjs from "dayjs";
import * as customParseFormat from "dayjs/plugin/customParseFormat";
dayjs.extend(customParseFormat);
```

**CORRECT**:

```js
import dayjs from "dayjs";
import customParseFormat from "dayjs/plugin/customParseFormat";
dayjs.extend(customParseFormat);
```